# Train Chatbot with only custom knowledge and not general knowledge using ChatGPT API

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

So now I am coding in Python a chatbot using the ChatGPT API, and the issue that I have is that I want the chatbot to only have custom knowledge that will be trained from a PDF file, and not general knowledge.

So the function I used to embed the PDF file is the following:

```
# Function to embed the text
def get_vectorstore(text_chunks, api_key):
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=api_key)
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(text_chunks, embedding=embeddings)
    return vectorstore
```

And the code I use to train the chatbot is the following?

```
# Train the bot with the PDF information
def get_conversation_chain(vectorstore, api_key):
    llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=api_key)
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key='chat_history',  return_messages=True)
    conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm = llm,
        retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        memory = memory
    )
    return conversation_chain
```

Any ideas on how I can train the chatbot using only custom knowledge?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Transforming any PDF or document into a fully functional chatbot with ChatGPT may not be possible directly out-of-the-box. However, you can follow a structured process to achieve this transformation using a combination of tools and techniques. Check this [link](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/transform-document-into-a-chatbot/) for all the information

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the link! However I was looking for a way to achieve this using 100% code :(